# flutter web why is there a hashtag in the url?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to know why is there a hashtag in the URL? for the Flutter web app, eg: `http://localhost:64392/#/home` even in production same result.

I want to know why and also if possible to remove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove the `#` in the URL, it [is documented here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-the-url-strategy):

> To configure Flutter to use the path instead, use the
> usePathUrlStrategy function provided by the flutter_web_plugins
> library in the SDK:

> ```
> import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';
>
> void main() {
>   usePathUrlStrategy();
>   runApp(ExampleApp());
> }
> ```

And add this to your `pubsepc.yaml`:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
```

---

Additionally, you can use the [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package.

See [turning off the hash](https://docs.page/csells/go_router/url-path-strategy#turning-off-the-hash):

> ```
> void main() {
>   // turn on the # in the URLs on the web (default)
>   // GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy(UrlPathStrategy.hash);
>
>   // turn off the # in the URLs on the web
>   GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy(UrlPathStrategy.path);
>
>   runApp(App());
> }
> ```

Comment: okay thanks, that's helpful, but do you know why is there a hashtag in the URL? by default

Comment: @lordyhas Not sure why, that's just the way it works..

Comment: It seams the "#" character tells the browser that this is a client-side route and that the navigation should be handled by the application, rather than making a new request to the server. Flutter uses the hashtag convention by default to provide a consistent and predictable URL structure for client-side routing.